# apache log analyzer with IP information is needed

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I am not sure if here is the right place for asking my question or not... anyway...

I need a apache log analyzer that shows number of each IP request separately. I want to view what IPs have visited my website more times.

My server OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: Duplicate by same person: http://serverfault.com/questions/375794/a-software-to-analyze-apache-log-is-needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWStats - http://awstats.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: i have 4 different websites on this server that i have separated their log files.Does AWStats works separately for these 4 sites?

Comment: It's been a while since I "fired" it up, but I think so. I think it can either be broken down as individual sessions/setups or track/report by accessing URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Try Apache Logs Viewer. Should display graphical reports and filter based on specific criteria.

http://www.apacheviewer.com

Answer (score 1):

GoAccess - http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com

No configuration is needed and you can run it straight from the terminal + real-time stats