# A software to analyze Apache log is needed

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I have grep the Apache logs of my website for a specific period of time. I need a software to analyze it to see what are the most visitor IPs .

My OS is Ubuntu.

Would you suggest something?

Thank you.

Comment: Look into [Webalizer](http://webalizer.linux-mirror.org/) (written in C) and [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) (written in Perl) - both are well known logfile analyzers. Or if you just want to see the most IPs, try `awk '{!a[$1]++}END{for(i in a) if ( a[i] >10 ) print a[i],i }' access.log` (which will display an IP and count for those IPs with more than 10 views).

Comment: thank you.how can I sort the output of the command you write?

Comment: Pipe it through sort - e.g.: `... | sort -n -r` (for numerical and reverse order (i.e. largest first))

Comment: Duplicate by same person: http://serverfault.com/questions/286342/apache-log-analyzer-with-ip-information-is-needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of logfile analyzer packages that exist - two of which are [Webalizer](http://webalizer.linux-mirror.org/) (written in C) and [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) (written in Perl). Both should also be available through the Ubuntu repositories. These will parse your logfiles and generate reports for you to view (typically through a web browser, although, they can generate text reports as well).

Traditionally, they are setup to run automatically (e.g. via cron) and the latest report is available by accessing a particular path under your domain, and/or is emailed to you. (As you may expect, both do require some setup to produce what you want).

If you just want get a list of which IP addresses have made the most requests, a one-time bash command is likely easier than setting up either of the above. Try:

```
awk '{!a[$1]++}END{for(i in a) if ( a[i] >10 ) print a[i],i }' access.log | sort -n -r
```

Essentially, create an array using the IP address as the index, increasing the counter with each match - and display those results with more than 10 matches. Pipe the result through `sort` to display in descending order.

If you have already used `grep` to filter your list, you can pipe the output of your that command through (a slight variation of) the one above.

For instance, for a list of IP addresses that made more than 10 requests, today, between midnight and 4am (not inclusive) (presuming that data is in access.log):

```
grep '02/Apr/2012:0[0-3]' access.log | awk '{!a[$1]++}END{for(i in a) if ( a[i] >10 ) print a[i],i }' | sort -n -r
```

Sample output:

```
40 66.xxx.xx.xx
35 184.xx.xxx.xx
26 147.xx.xxx.xx
18 74.xxx.xx.xxx
17 209.xx.xxx.xxx
15 14.xxx.xxx.xx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested, ManageEngine has a solution called EventLog Analyzer. It will analyze Apache web server logs and generate exhaustive reports. You can try.